# iOS :Upgrade Cordova 1.5 to Cordova 2.7.0 in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

Can anyone please tell me how to upgrade Cordova Framework from 1.5.0 to 2.7.0 in XCode ? I am using XCode version 4.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Cordova 2.7.0 you will need Xcode 4.5 or higher. Then just install the Cordova SDK.

You will need to be running OSX Lion or higher.

Comment: @rockoenes: oh Ok.. thanq for your reply.. :)